# Exiting a SpringBoot app - how do I get a reference to SpringApplication?

Tags: spring-boot

I realize that to programmatically exit a SpringBoot 4 application I want to call the exit() method of SpringApplication, but how can I get a reference to it?

Of course I have access to it in my main() method, but I ask because if I'm in some class that is loading a resource and fails, I want to terminate the app, but from that class I can't figure out how to access SpringApplication.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach for this use case is to use events & listeners wherein you have to add your listener to SpringApplication class which will listens to an event like in your case a resource load failure and then subsequently act accordingly i.e. exit the application. You can get application context handle by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface. Details on event & listener can be found [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2).

MyEvent class :-

```
public class MyEvent extends ContextRefreshedEvent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    public MyEvent(ApplicationContext source) {
        super(source);
    }

}
```

MyEvent listener class :-

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {       
        if(event instanceof MyEvent){
            SpringApplication.exit(event.getApplicationContext(), new ExitCodeGenerator() {
                @Override
                public int getExitCode() {
                    return 2;
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Resource loader class:-

```
@Component
public class MyResourceLoader implements ApplicationContextAware, CommandLineRunner {

    private ApplicationContext ctx ;    

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //inside RUN for resource load failure
        publisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent(ctx));       
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was not aware of that. I read it, but I was not clear on whether or not I can create my own events to listen for?

Comment: Yes you can. Pls check the sample code above to explain the implementation on my answer above.